# pandas group by product instead of sum or count

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

In python pandas, I want to group a dataframe by column and then take the product of the rows for each ID. Sum and count functions exist, but a product?

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['B', 'B', 'A', 'A'], 'Y' : [1, 2, 3, 4]})

print(df2.groupby(['X']).sum())
   Y
X   
A  7
B  3

print(df2.groupby(['X']).count())
   Y
X   
A  2
B  2
```

How can I take the product of the items instead of the sum or count?

```
print(df2.groupby(['X']).product())
   Y
X   
A  12
B  2
```

Comment: Your example is backwards, the product of A is 12 and B is 2.

Comment: that was indeed typo. I corrected the example

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is `prod`:

```
df.groupby('X').prod()
```