# How to multiply rows of one column after groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
 user  percent 
  x      0.2
  x      0.5
  x      0.8
  y      0.1
  y      0.6
  y      0.2
  y      0.6
```

I am trying to multiply the percents in the rows for each user.

In the example, the result for x will be 0.2*0.5*0.8 = 0.08

The dataframe should therefore look like that:

```
user     result
  x      0.08
  y      0.0072
```

How to get my expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas group by product instead of sum or count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290729/pandas-group-by-product-instead-of-sum-or-count)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`groupby` + `prod`.

```
df.groupby('user', as_index=False).prod()

  user  percent
0    x   0.0800
1    y   0.0072
```

Or, using `apply` + `np.prod` -

```
df.groupby('user', as_index=False).apply(np.prod)

  user  percent
0    x   0.0800
1    y   0.0072
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried both of your answers and the first one was exactly what i wanted.

Comment: @Liron You're welcome! I realised there was a copy paste error with the second, but that should also work now.

Answer (score 2):

`cumprod` + `iloc[-1]`

```
df.groupby('user').percent.apply(lambda x : x.cumprod().iloc[-1])
Out[532]: 
user
x    0.0800
y    0.0072
Name: percent, dtype: float64
```